# Fastest way to code iteration through XML items using python's minidom?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

What would be the shortest code/fastest way to put the `feature` in a dictionary, using python's minidom for this structure of xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns       = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id          = "http://example.org/exampleWidget"
        version     = "2.0 Beta"
        height      = "200"
        width       = "200"
        viewmodes   = "fullscreen">

<feature name="http://example.com/camera" state="true"/>
<feature name="http://example.com/bluetooth" state="true"/>
<feature name="http://example.com/sms" state="true"/>
<feature name="http://example.com/etc" state="false"/>
</widget>
```

I'm not interested for now in widget's attributes just the features.

The output would be 
`feature["camera"] = true`
`feature["etc"] = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from os.path import basename

dom = parseString(raw_xml)

feature = {}
for f in dom.getElementsByTagName('feature'):
    name = basename(f.getAttribute('name'))
    state = f.getAttribute('state').lower() == 'true'
    feature[name] = state
```

**Or in SHORT:**

```
dict([(basename(f.getAttribute('name')), f.getAttribute('state').lower() == 'true')
  for f in parseString(raw).getElementsByTagName('feature')])
```